# How to read the attachment of sharepoint online lists using the Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

For Attachment Items in any list of SharePoint Online, graph explorer can get only Attachments property which contains value “true” or “false”.

Using Rest API we can easily expand and grab the attached links. However, Using Graph Explorer we can not expand the Attachments property.

The below query I have tried in Graph Explorer: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/items/%7Bitem-id%7D)

Attachments: true

How can we get the attachments.

Comment: What do you mean by Rest API? Sharepoint REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user2250152 said, currently this is not supported in Graph API. You could submit the feature request here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving `List Item` attachment details is not supported.

So far, you can use only Sharepoint REST [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)